# ConEmu: Can't pass Ctrl-PageDown to vim

Tags: vim, conemu

I use vim in ConEmu. And I want to use `Ctrl+PageDown` and `Ctrl+PageUp` to switch through the tab pages.
I cancelled `Ctrl+PageDown` and `Ctrl+PageUp` in Hotkey list, and tried GuiMacro like `print()` and `keys()`. But vim can't get my key bindings.
How can I pass `Ctrl-PageDown` or other key bindings properly to vim?

Comment: What do you do to check these keypresses?

Comment: @Maximus I have the same problem as OP. The shortcut Ctrl+PageUp is bind to scrolling down in ConEmu. I disabled that and then in the console I now receive `5~` which in vim leads to apply tilde command 5 times (turning lower case to upper case). The mapping I use for vim is `noremap <C-PageUp> :tabnext<CR>`